# Can I Deploy Laravel App To A Shared Hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment, shared-hosting

I'm wondering if it's possible to deploy a **laravel 7** app that I've built using **vuejs 2** to a **shared hosting** using **ftp** to upload files.
I also want to hint that **security** is essential when uploading the app.
If this is possible I would like to know how it is done.

Comment: you could check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4)

Comment: What have you tried so far? . It is possible

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

1. Go into the laravel-vue project and build the production version of the app.
2. Make sure that hidden files are visible then compress everything but the node_modules
3. Go to your cpanel, create a folder for your new app in the root (not public_html)
4. Upload and extract the compressed file into the new folder you just created
5. Move the content of the public folder except .htaccess into the root of the new folder you just made
6. Create a new .htaccess file in the root of this same folder and add these:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   ```
7. Edit the index.php file in this same folder by changing:

require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; **to** require **DIR**.'/vendor/autoload.php';

require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; **to** require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';

8. Create a subdomain for this app and set the document root to the folder we created and placed all the laravel files into this folder. Open your domain and your website will start working.